# Swap program halves to test divisors

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, number-theory, source-layout, multiple-holes

### Four integer sequences

In this challenge, you will test four different properties of a positive integer, given by the following sequences.
A positive integer **N** is

1. *perfect* ([OEIS A000396](https://oeis.org/A000396)), if the sum of proper divisors of **N** equals **N**. The sequence begins with 6, 28, 496, 8128, 33550336, 8589869056, 137438691328, 2305843008139952128...
2. *refactorable* ([OEIS A033950](https://oeis.org/A033950)), if the number of divisors of **N** is a divisor of **N**. The sequence begins with 1, 2, 8, 9, 12, 18, 24, 36, 40, 56, 60, 72, 80, 84, 88, 96, 104, 108, 128...
3. *practical* ([OEIS A005153](https://oeis.org/A005153)), if every integer **1 ≤ K ≤ N** is a sum of some distinct divisors of **N**. The sequence begins with 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 18, 20, 24, 28, 30, 32, 36, 40, 42, 48, 54, 56...
4. *highly composite* ([OEIS A002128](https://oeis.org/A002182)), if every number **1 ≤ K < N** has strictly fewer divisors than **N**. The sequence begins with 1, 2, 4, 6, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 120, 180, 240, 360, 720, 840, 1260, 1680, 2520, 5040...

### Four programs

Your task is to write four programs (meaning full programs, function definitions or anonymous functions that perform I/O by any of the [standard methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/32014)).
Each program shall solve the membership problem of one of these sequences.
In other words, each program will take a positive integer **N ≥ 1** as input, and output a truthy value if **N** is in the sequence, and a falsy value if not.
You can assume that **N** is within the bounds of the standard integer type of your programming language.

The programs must be related in the following way.
There are four strings `ABCD` such that

1. `AC` is the program that recognizes perfect numbers.
2. `AD` is the program that recognizes refactorable numbers.
3. `BC` is the program that recognizes practical numbers.
4. `BD` is the program that recognizes highly composite numbers.

### Scoring

Your score is the total length (in bytes) of the strings `ABCD`, or in other words, the total byte count of the four programs divided by two.
The lowest score in each programming language is the winner.
Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

For example, if the four strings are `a{`, `b{n`, `+n}` and `=n}?`, then the four programs are `a{+n}`, `a{=n}?`, `b{n+n}` and `b{n=n}?`, and the score is 2+3+3+4=12.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24258/calculate-practical-numbers), [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58026/am-i-perfect-number), [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/74487/highly-composite-numbers).

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), 46 + 55 + 6 + 36 = <s>282</s> <s>274</s> ... <s>158</s> 143 bytes

A:

```
n=>(r=0,D=x=>x&&D(x-1,n%x||(r++?q-=x:q=n)))(n)
```

B:

```
n=>(q=(g=D=x=>x&&!(n%x||(g|=m>2*(m=x),0))+D(x-1))(m=n))
```

C:

```
?!g:!q
```

D:

```
?(P=k=>--k?D(n=k)<q&P(k):1)(n):n%r<1
```

The result is 4 anonymous functions which give truthy/falsy values for their respective inputs (`AC`, `AD`, and `BC` give `true`/`false`, `BD` gives `1`/`0`).

#### Test snippet

```js
let AC =
n=>(r=0,D=x=>x&&D(x-1,n%x||(r++?q-=x:q=n)))(n)
?!g:!q

let AD =
n=>(r=0,D=x=>x&&D(x-1,n%x||(r++?q-=x:q=n)))(n)
?(P=k=>--k?D(n=k)<q&P(k):1)(n):n%r<1

let BC =
n=>(q=(g=D=x=>x&&!(n%x||(g|=m>2*(m=x),0))+D(x-1))(m=n))
?!g:!q

let BD =
n=>(q=(g=D=x=>x&&!(n%x||(g|=m>2*(m=x),0))+D(x-1))(m=n))
?(P=k=>--k?D(n=k)<q&P(k):1)(n):n%r<1

let update = n => O.innerText = [
  'perfect: ' + AC(n),
  'refactorable: ' + AD(n),
  'practical: ' + BC(n),
  'highly composite: ' + BD(n)
].join("\n")
```

```html
<input type=number value=1 min=1 oninput=update(this.value)>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: I like how you have spread the actual code over all 4 parts and mixed it with the "conditionals" unlike me (I have the code on parts A and B and "conditionals" on parts C and D.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 + 17 + <s>2</s> 1 + 2 = <s>29</s> 28 bytes

A:

```
Æṣ⁼$Ædḍ$
```

B:

```
ÆDŒPS€QṢwRµṖÆdṀ<Ʋ
```

C:

```
ƭ
```

D:

```
0?
```

For practical numbers (BC), `0` is falsy and any other result is truthy.

AC and BC are full programs, since they're not reusable as functions.

Comment: BC and BD don't seem to work properly.

Comment: `ÆDŒPS€ḟ@RṆµṖÆd<ÆdẠµ` works as B for a cost of two bytes though (and makes BC return 0 and 1 only like the others).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh no, it seems that I confused `ŒP` with `ŒṖ`. What a shame! Does it work if you fix that? (i.e. try my new edit) It's not that it's very easy to test anyway, that's why I haven't included a TIO link yet.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 + 17 + 3 + 3 = 28 bytes

There's already a 28-byte Jelly answer, but I have a different approach, so why not add it too?

### Parts

The pilcrow `¶` represents a newline.

A: `S=¶ḍ¶` (5 bytes)
B: `ŒP§iⱮḶ}Ạ¶>ḶÆd$}Ạ¶` (17 bytes)
C: `ÆḌñ` (3 bytes)
D: `Ædç` (3 bytes)

### Perfect (8 bytes)

```
S=
ḍ
ÆḌñ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/Yluvhjl6uw20Pd/Qc3vj//38zAA)

#### Explanation

```
S=   Auxiliary dyadic link
S    Sum of items in left argument
 =   Equals right argument?

ḍ   Ignored

ÆḌñ   Main monadic link
ÆḌ    Proper divisors
  ñ   Apply next link, with the number as right argument
```

### Refactorable (8 bytes)

```
S=
ḍ
Ædç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/Yluvhjl6uw20ph5f////fyAIA)

#### Explanation

```
S=   Ignored

ḍ   Auxiliary dyadic link: Divides?

Ædç   Main monadic link
Æd    Number of divisors
  ç   Apply previous link, with the number as right argument
```

### Practical (20 bytes)

```
ŒP§iⱮḶ}Ạ
>ḶÆd$}Ạ
ÆḌñ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIBDyzMfbVz3cMe22oe7FnDZARmH21JUwJzDbQ939Bze@P//f3MA)

#### Explanation

```
ŒP§iⱮḶ}Ạ   Auxiliary dyadic link
ŒP         Power set
  §        Sum of each
   iⱮ      Find index of each item from
     Ḷ}      Lowered range [0..(right argument - 1)]
       Ạ   All?

>ḶÆd$}Ạ   Ignored

ÆḌñ   Main monadic link
ÆḌ    Proper divisors
  ñ   Apply next link, with the number as right argument
```

### Highly composite (20 bytes)

```
ŒP§iⱮḶ}Ạ
>ḶÆd$}Ạ
Ædç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIBDyzMfbVz3cMe22oe7FnDZARmH21JUwBwg4/Dy////WwAA)

#### Explanation

```
ŒP§iⱮḶ}Ạ   Ignored

>ḶÆd$}Ạ   Auxiliary dyadic link
>         Greater than?
    $     (
 Ḷ   }      Lowered range [0..(right argument - 1)]
  Æd        Number of divisors [of each]
    $     )
      Ạ   All?

Ædç   Main monadic link
Æd    Number of divisors
  ç   Apply previous link, with the number as right argument
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 + 16 + 1 + 0 = 25 bytes

A: `Ñ¨O©QI®Ö`
B: `ÑæOILåPILÑ€gRć‹P`
C: `s`
D:

The long parts each calculate both values, `s` swaps to the first one.

```
Ñ          # push list of divisors
 ©         # store this list
  ¨        # remove the last (largest) value
   O       # take the sum
    Q      # is this equal to the input (perfect)
     I     # push the input
      ®    # push the stored divisor list
       g   # take the length
        Ö  # does it divide the input? (refactorable)
        (s)# (swap to perfect)
```

[Try *perfect* online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MRDKw@t8A/0PLQu/fC04v//DS0A) or [Try *refactorable* online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MRDKw@t8A/0PLQu/fC0//8NLQA)

```
ÑæOILåP    # practical?
Ñ          # push list of divisors
 æ         # take the powerset
  O        # sum of each subset
   IL      # push the range [1..input]
     å     # is each value in the sums of divisor-subsets?
      P    # take the product / boolean all

ILÑ€gRć‹P  # highly composite?
IL         # push the range [1..input]
  Ñ        # take the divisors of each integer
   €g      # take the length of each divisor list
     R     # reverse it (swap the input's to the front)
      ć    # push the first value seperately
       ‹   # is this larger
        P  # than all other values?

(s)        # (swap to practical)
```

[Try *practical* online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MTDy/w9fQ4vDQASEx81rUkPOtL@qGFnQPH//4YWAA) or [Try *highly composite* online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MTDy/w9fQ4vDQASEx81rUkPOtL@qGFnwP//hhYA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 69 + 133 + 3 + 3 = score 208

A:

```hs
d n=filter((<1).mod n)[1..n]
f n=[sum(d n)-n==n,length(d n)`elem`d n]
```

B:

```hs
import Data.List
d n=filter((<1).mod n)[1..n]
f n=[all(\n->any(==n)$sum$subsequences$d n)[1..n],all((<length(d n)).length.d)[1..n-1]]
```

C:

```hs
!!0
```

D:

```hs
!!1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rU@7DsIwDNzzFanUIZWaiDBWFAnoyB9AJQJNISIxpQkDQnx7cal4jAwMlnxn@@58UP6ore1unM4yUlHIa2ODbhmbyES4EzLJSgoBJalxuPIXx3qOQ55DajXsw@FJbLTVboNdSfidENSbZ8S45tQGWqigxNL48IOBspatgU8VXBlaJDE6Ym29Pl807LSPPxdpv8wmXykSMQBRDStclu88i4xE0eiFih5JRN1fnkblzikDNKdNayDQmNZUjrsH)

Yeah, it's pretty cheap but I'm not smart enough for a cooler solution. :P

Comment: I don't know much about Haskell but [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153022/77598) could help you with `subsequences`

Comment: `[x|x<-[1..n],mod n x<1]` is shorter than `filter((<1).mod n)[1..n]`.